# Use yarn global install,An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/umi'"

Tags: yarnpkg

When I use yarn global install packages ,I will see the error "An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/umi'". Now,I use nvm to control my node version.

My system is MacOs 10.15.3 and node version is v10.15.0.

Now,I use nvm to control node version.

```sh
yarn global add umi
```

```
# show error
yarn global v1.22.4
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Installed "umi@3.2.10" with binaries:
      - umi
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/umi'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/jokky/.config/yarn/global/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

first ,I open the file .yarnrc.

add next line text

```
prefix "/path/.config/yarn"
```

this path is your yarn download path